# how to change the image url based on color click in angular inside ngFor

Tags: angular

**component.ts**

```
    //all imports are done
    
ngOnInit() {
      this.list = {
          'eatList': [{
            'class': 'Fruits',
            'color': ['Red', 'White', 'Black'],
            'imageSrc': ['/assets/images/fruit/red-fruit.png', 
              '/assets/images/fruit/black-fruit.png',
              '/assets/images/fruit/white-fruit.png']
          },
          {
            'modalName': 'Vegetable',
            'color': ['Green', 'Black'],
            'imageSrc': ['/assets/images/veg/black-veg.png', /assets/images/veg/green-veg.png']

}
```

**component.html**

```
<div>
  <div *ngFor="let eats of list.eatList" "
   >
    <h3>{{eats.class}}</h3>
    <img src="{{eats.imageSrc[0]}}" alt="image" />

    
    <p>COLOR</p>
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <button *ngFor="let color of eats.color" class="dot" [style.background-color]="color"
        (click)="colorChange(eats, color)"></button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

On click of colorChange function I want to change the `<img>` src url of the respective item only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's always the same, you need add a "new property" to your "estList", e.g. "index". So

```
this.list.forEach(x=>{x.index=0}); //or when you create the list
```

**Update: WRONG**

```
<!--this code is wrong, see the coded updated below--/
<img src="{{eats.imageSrc[eats.index]}}" alt="image" />
<button *ngFor="let color of eats.color" class="dot" [style.background-color]="color"
        (click)="eats.index=(eats.index+1)%3"></button>
```

**Update** The good code is

```
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let eats of list.eatList">
        <h3>{{eats.class}}</h3>
        <img src="{{eats.imageSrc[eats.index]}}" alt="image" />
        <p>COLOR</p>
        <div style="text-align:center">
            <button *ngFor="let color of eats.color;let i=index" class="dot" [style.background-color]="color"
        (click)="eats.index=i">{{color}}</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but where are we changing the imageSrc in the `<img>` tag ? on click of colorChange function ? I mean I want to achieve when i click on the color in UI the respective url of the image gets updated for the respective item.

Comment: ::glups:: is `(click)="eats.index=(eats.index+1)%3"` , just corrected in answer, sorry. when I click the variable is incremented. The module operator makes that if the vriable becomes 3, the variable gets the value 0. Tecnically was better write `(click)="eats.index=(eatx.index+1%eats.color.length)"`

Comment: list.forEach is not a funstion // error thrown

Comment: my bad!! sorry again, `this.list.eatList.forEach`

Comment: i am adding after loading the list inside ngOnInit() the forEach code.

Comment: is there any other solution ? because it fails when the array value is 2

Comment: Defintly I need more coffe. see the stackblitz:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pabycn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html, apologies for your loose time, I updated the answer

Comment: working... thanks much! I wanted to learn the way you think :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227034/discussion-between-aditya-and-eliseo).